# Synaptics touchpad inactive before suspend, active after resume

Tags: ubuntu, suspend, touchpad

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04. I usually disable the touchpad. (because my palms make the cursor jump all over the screen!)

When I suspend (by closing my laptop's lid) and then resume (by opening the lid), the touchpad is reactivated.

How can I get Ubuntu to remember and restore the touchpad's state after suspend/resume?